# Решить задачу по информатике (уровень школы)

Tags: python

Текст задачи:
5969 (Уровень: Базовый)
(Д. Статный) Исполнитель Калькулятор преобразует число, записанное на экране. У исполнителя есть четыре команды, которым присвоены номера:

А. Прибавить ближайшее число, которое можно представить в разложении суммой двух квадратов чисел.
Б. Прибавить ближайшее простое число.
В. Прибавить ближайшее число, являющееся степенью 2.
Г. Прибавить минимальное двузначное число, которое можно получить разностью квадратов двух цифр числа.

Сколько существует таких программ, которые преобразуют исходное число 4 в 4-е совершенное число, а траектория содержит от 1 до 6 чисел Фибоначчи включительно?
Примечание: Совершенное число - число, равное сумме своих делителей, отличных от самого числа.
Команды А, Б, В прибавляют числа, большие исходного.

Мой код для решение задачи:

```
from itertools import combinations as c
from functools import cache

@cache
def fib(n):
    return n if n <= 1 else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
s = [fib(i) for i in range(300)]

A = lambda x: x if any([1 if a*a+b*b==x else 0 for a, b in c(range(x//2), 2)]) else A(x+1) # Проверка условия А
B = lambda x: x if len([1 for i in range(1,x+1) if x%i==0])== 2 else B(x+1) # Проверка условия Б
C = lambda x, k: t if (t:=2**k) > x else C(x,k+1) # Проверка условия В

def D(x): # Функция для проверки условия Г
    try:
        return min([t for a, b in c([int(i) for i in list(str(x))], 2) if len(str(abs((t:=min(a,b)**2 - max(a,b)**2)))) == 2])
    except: return 0

@cache
def fn(x, k, m, p):
    if k == 4 and 6 >= m >= 1: return 1 # Число должно быть четвёртое, при этом путь в себе содержит числа фибоначчи в промежутке от 1 до 7
    if k >= 4 or m > 6 or p>=999: return 0
    k = k+1 if sum([i for i in range(1,x) if x%i==0]) == x else k; global s # проверка совершенного числа
    m = m+1 if x in s else m # проверка вхождения числа x в числа фибоначчи
    return fn(x+B(x+1),k,m,p+1) + fn(x+A(x+1),k,m,p+1) + fn(x+C(x,0),k,m,p+1) + fn(x+D(x),k,m,p+1) 
print(fn(4, 0, 0, 0))
```

Должен получится ответ: 36970

Почему у меня не получается, может ошибка в проверке условий?

Comment: код текстом, пожалуйста

Comment: Ни фига себе "базовый школьный уровень"...

Comment: Прочитайте, что такое совершенные числа. Вам нужно получить 8128

Comment: Я понял) Пытаюсь сейчас корректировать код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations as c
from functools import cache

@cache
def fib(n):
    return n if n <= 1 else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
s = [fib(i) for i in range(300)]

#n = [x for x in range(1,10000) if sum([y for y in range(1,x) if not x%y]) == x][-1] из этой строки узнаём,что 4-е совершенное число 8128
A = sorted([x*x+y*y for x in range(70) for y in range(70)]) # -
B = [i for i in range(5, 4444) if sum([1 for m in range(1,i+1) if i%m==0]) == 2] 
C = [2**k for k in range(3,18)] 
li = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}
f = lambda x, y: t[0] if len((t:=list(filter(lambda u: u>x, li[y])))) > 0 else 10**20 

def D(x): 
    try:
        return min([t for x, y in c(map(int, list(str(x))), 2) if len(str((t:=abs(x*x-y*y)))) == 2])
    except: return 0

@cache
def fn(x, y, k):
    if x >= y: return x == y and 6 >= k >= 1
    k += 1 if x in s else 0
    return (fn(x+D(x), y, k) if D(x) else 0) + fn(x+f(x,'A'), y, k) + fn(x+f(x,'B'), y, k) + fn(x+f(x,'C'), y, k)
print(fn(4, 8128, 0))
```

Вот решение!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]